Unable to Import `bm3d` Package in Google Colab After Installation
I am trying to use the bm3d package for image denoising in Google Colab. I was able to use it without any issues a few days ago. However, now I am facing an import error even though the package installs successfully.

Install the bm3d package:
!pip install bm3d

Try to import the bm3d package:
import bm3d


Observed Error:
ImportError: cannot import name '_sub_module_deprecation' from 
'scipy._lib.deprecation' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/deprecation.py)

How to resolve the issue and import the package in colab?

bm3d package you are using depends on a specific version of scipy causing the import error. To resolve this issue, you can try installing a compatible version of scipy along with the bm3d package.
Please use the following commands for this.
!pip uninstall scipy -y 
!pip install scipy==1.8.0 
!pip install bm3d 

import bm3d 


I follow your instruction to import bm3d but when i import bm3d it show below error
OSError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bm4d/libbm4d.so)

On Ubuntu, pls update libstdc++ by running the following commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
